# Return outputs with zero counts

Tags: qiskit, programming, experimental-realization

I am running a simple 3 qubit circuit which produces the following results:

```
{'000': 5, '001': 3, '010': 10, '100': 5, '101': 7, '110': 7, '111': 4}
```

There are no counts of 011. Is there a simple way within qiskit to also return the result '011': 0? So the final results would be

```
{'000': 5, '001': 3, '010': 10,'011': 0, '100': 5, '101': 7, '110': 7, '111': 4}
```

Currently when I run this circuit I get an error as I am trying to call res['011'], where res is the list of results. I cannot just increase the number of shots unfortunately I am constrained to this number of qubits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.get()](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.result.Counts.get.html#qiskit.result.Counts.get) and return zero as the default value.

`res.get('011', 0)`